# Laravel, show row value on <p> tag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I know this should be something easy but I don't figured out how to do it:

I have multiple "delet" buttons implemented on a datatable, and want to show a modal with the dialog: Do you reall want to delete: , but I don't know how to put the  sentence.

This is my View:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="message">
                <h3> BORRAR TIPO </h3>

                {{ Form::model($catalog["nambe"], array('method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => 'type', 'route' => array($catalog["name"].'.destroy', $catalog["id"]))) }}

                    <br>
                    <p>Do you reall want to delete: {{ //I whant to display the exactly name of that button }} </p>

                    <br>
                    {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                {{ Form::close() }}

        </div>
    //mode code below
```

In my DB I have:

```
name of table    |type|
                 |id  |
                 |name|
```

And I Want to show the name of the exact type than I press, but don't know how to do it, can someone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a javascript issue. I've fixed this many times with this:

```
<div class="modal" id="your-modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="message">
                <h3> BORRAR TIPO </h3>

                {{ Form::model($catalog["nambe"], array('method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => 'type', 'route' => array($catalog["name"].'.destroy', $catalog["id"]))) }}

                    <br>
                    <p>Do you reall want to delete: <span id="deleteSentence"></span></p>

                    <br>
                    {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                {{ Form::close() }}

        </div>
```

And with this script you can change the value of the span:

```
<script>
    $('#your-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#deleteSentence').html($(e.relatedTarget).data('sentence'));
    });
</script>
```

And then add the invoker button:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-sentence="{{$name}}" data-target="#your-modal" href="http://some-url" >Launch Modal</a>
```

If you wan't to send the name with you're form then put a hidden input field in the modal.